# Stack navigator header button doesn't navigate to route on press

Tags: react-native

Here is my error: `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')`

My goal  is to navigate to my `Settings` page when on click  on my `LeftHeader` component in my StackNavigator:

Here is a snippet of my `App.js` file:

```js
const FeedStackNav = () => {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          options={{
            title: "",
            headerLeft: ({ navigation }) => (
              <Header>
                <LeftHeader onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Settings")}>
                  <MenuIcon fill={"#C13B1E"} />
                </LeftHeader>
              </Header>
            ),
           
          }}
          name="Feed"
          component={Feed}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    );
  };
```

And here is how I am rendering the Stack in my app:

```js
<NavigationContainer theme={theme}>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen
            options={{
              headerShown: false, 
            }}
            name=" "
            component={TabNav}
          />

          <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
```

There has to be something wrong with my `LeftHeader` onPress function

Comment: `headerLeft` function don't have any params, you have to use `navigation.addOptions` in your component to add the `headerLeft` to access the same `navigation`

Comment: @Tj3n Can you show me an example? I can't seem to  find it in the docs

Comment: [Here it is](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons/#header-interaction-with-its-screen-component). Ah sorry you can also access `navigation` via `options={({ navigation, route }) => {}`. No need to use `addOptions` it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Am adding  just snippet of code to illustrate how to use `navigation.navigate('screen')` on header button

```
 <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator
          screenOptions={{
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
            },
            headerTintColor: '#fff',
            headerTitleStyle: {
              fontWeight: 'bold',
            },
          }}>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={HomeScreen}
            options={({navigation, route}) => ({
              headerRight: () => (
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => alert('Just clicked!!')}>
                  <FontIcon
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('CreateSession')}
                    name="video-camera"
                    color={whitish}
                    size={25}
                  />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              ),
            })}
          />
          <Stack.Screen name="CreateSession" component={CreateSessionScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="LiveSessions" component={LiveSession} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
```

on above code observe the callback function used to get access to `navigation` and `route` props

```
options={({navigation, route}) => ({
                  headerRight: () => (
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => alert('Just clicked!!')}>
                      <FontIcon
                        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('CreateSession')}
                        name="video-camera"
                        color={whitish}
                        size={25}
                      />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  ),
                })}
```